# Centering a group of Bootstrap DIVs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, center

How to center a group of DIVs centered inside container class but without centering each row?
In the following example can be seen a margin on the right area of the gray div whichs makes the group not to be showed in the center of the container. Using a justify-content-center will also center the last unpair row which I don't want. The idea is to have a responsible group of divs. Please advice:

```
<div class="container  bg-success">
  <p>centering divs</p>
  <div class="p-0  m-0 bg-dark d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">  
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want all rows to have centered items except for the last one that has to be aligned left?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple classes inside the class attribute, separated by whitespace
`<a class="c1 c2">aa</a>` and
`text-align`in your CSS like that

```css
.center{
text-align: center;
}
.left{
text-align: left;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container  bg-success">
  <p>centering divs</p>
  <div class="p-0  m-0 bg-dark d-flex flex-row flex-wrap center">  
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Three</div>
    <div class="bg-danger">One</div>
    <div class="bg-warning">Two</div>
    <div class="bg-primary left">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For mo info http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/multiple-classes/

Comment: You do realize `text-center` and `text-left` is part of the BS typography? I believe OP know that.  Also it is a hardcoded solution that really not solves anything  - what if there is appended two more items to the container runtime? I could not find a pure BS solution myself.